# Why doesn't pyGame or pyglet support python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pyglet

I have been looking into various game design modules for python such as pyglet and pyGame. I have noticed that both of these seem to only be compatible with python 2. Seeing as python 3 is the most current version, why is this? My experience with python has been with python 3, so are there good frameworks/modules out there for python 3 game development? Or would I be better off learning python 2 and using pyglet or pyGame?

edit: I would be using pyGame on a mac. The downloads page, http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml, only has links for py2.6, py2.5, and py2.4, which is what leads me to believe it is not python 3 compatible.

Answer (score 5):

I don't even get your question, as PyGame is compatible with Python 3 since version 1.9:
http://www.pygame.org/wiki/python3porting?parent=todo

There are a few minor issues, but it is usable with Python 3.

Comment: Oh, that's good to hear, based on the downloads page I got the impression that pyGame was only compatible up to py2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing a pygame-based application on Mac OSX with python 3.  It definitely works fine, and so far I haven't run into any compatibility problems, though there are certainly other mac-specific pygame bugs that I have found.

That said, I can definitely confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

The fifth link from the top under "Windows" on the page you linked to clearly has py-3.1 in the name.

Comment: So there is python 3 support on windows but not mac?

Comment: @user530718: Yes, that would appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

They don't support Python 3, because nobody has made them support Python 3 yet. It's a bizarre question. :-)

PyGame seems to mostly support Python 3. There are some issues: (from http://www.pygame.org/wiki/python3porting?parent=todo )

- Complete unicode file name handling (fsencoding branch), then merge back into trunk (by mid Sept/10).
- update documentation to explain Unicode in Pygame
- work out final solution for open Python 3 IOBase objects: how to check abstract types from C. (Sept. 1, 2010) Probably the most practical solution is to just do duck typing.
- _movie - deferred until module is ready for release
- scrap (does some C string stuff that makes porting difficult)
- camera - what is the status of this module?

Nowhere does it say that it doesn't work for Python 3 on mac, and it seems unlikely to that that this would be the case. So you can try, but you will have to compile it yourself.

Pyglet doens't mention Python 3, so it's probably not ported.

Answer (score 0):

[pyglet 1.2](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/CHANGELOG) (alpha as of July 2012) works with Python 3.